# django python - changing slug not redirecting to 404 page

Tags: python, django

Below is my one of the view, I get the desired result on my url i.e

localhost/employee/0001/reportees

But when I change the slug of my url it doesn't redirect me to 404 page insted it will show the same result, both the above and below url gives me same result. how do I make page go to 404 when the slug is changed. Note: both shows same result tat means url has no effect on the generated result

localhost/employee/0002/reportees

```
class EmployeeReporteeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = employee
    template_name = "employee_reportees.html"
    slug_field = "slug"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.base_qs = super(EmployeeReporteeView, self).get_queryset()
        context = super(EmployeeReporteeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['primary_list'] =     self.base_qs.filter(primary=self.request.user.employee.empid)
        context['secondary_list'] = self.base_qs.filter(secondary=self.request.user.employee.empid)
        return context
```

just to give an idea, I have this below view for detail view where when I change the slug it redirects to 404
When employee 0001 is logged in this page shows his profile 
localhost/employee/0001
where as localhost/employee/0002  will redirect to 404 as he cannot see other employees detail

```
class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = employee
    template_name = "employee_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "employee_detail"
    def get_queryset(self):
        base_qs = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        return base_qs.filter(email=self.request.user)

# urls.py
     url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name="employee_detail"),
     url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/reportees/$", EmployeeReporteeView.as_view(), name="employee_reportees"),
```

Comment: I don't know why this question is given negative vote :( Is it something I have asked wrong? or is there less details explaining the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your queryset is based on one session value only (here the `request.user.employee.empid`). So every slug will give the same result, corresponding to the current logged employee.
If you want to show reportees of the slug written in the URL, you need to modify your queryset to use the `slug` parameter. Something like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    self.base_qs = super(EmployeeReporteeView, self).get_queryset()
    context = super(EmployeeReporteeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['primary_list'] = self.base_qs.filter(primary=self.kwargs['slug'])
    context['secondary_list'] = self.base_qs.filter(secondary=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return context
```